# JW player remove time from controlbar

Tags: jwplayer

How to disable timer in JWplayer controll panel? Need to remove only this value: [image] JWPlayer version=5.7.1896. Thanks!

Comment: You can use css .jw-text-duration{display:none!important}, is it flash player?

Comment: It is a flash player. but .jw-text-duration{display:none!important} has no effect. Maybe it depends on jwplayer version ? Now i have version 5.7